# Community Wiki status

Tags: discussion

I recently posted an answer that got flagged as CW because I made 13 edits to it. I requested the flag to be removed because I think that post settles problems with other posts. The moderator wrote in his answer: *“a CW answer should in no way be taken as an indication of being less correct”*.

The overall question is: How is a CW answer ranked? In particular, my guess is that a CW answer still receives votes just the reputation is not assigned to anyone. Is that correct? Also, can the original writer of the post vote on his own post once it reaches community status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He was responding to what you said in your flag:

> [...] If CW status stays, the post will not be able to raise votes and it might seem as if it is not a correct answer.

A CW post does not prevent any eligible user (≥ 15 rep, not the author) from voting for it, nor does the CW status imply that such an answer is "less worthy" or "incorrect". Except for reputation gain for the author, it behaves exactly like any other non CW answer.

Some examples of the questions and answers that were CW from the start, to encourage collaborative editing are:

- [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/5)
- [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/5) (Faysal's answer)
- [Can one identify the design patterns of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24988/5)

You'll find many more if you look around.

Comment: The only thing that I would add is: CW answers can be recognized by the change of the "author signature" (the little box at the bottom right of the post).